# Yii 2.0 table alias in SQL query

Tags: yii2

I am using Yii2.0 and I have following error when I doing filtering with relationship:

> Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'userContact.email' in 'where clause' The SQL being executed was:
>   SELECT `tbl_user`.* FROM `tbl_user` LEFT JOIN `tbl_user_contact` ON
>   `tbl_user`.`id` = `tbl_user_contact`.`user_id` WHERE
>   `userContact`.`email`='me@me.com'

And it is obvious that the table name alias is not given. Following is my code that generate the query above:

**Class Files**

```php
class User extends ActiveRecord{
    public function getUserContacts(){
        return $this->hasMany(UserContact::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

```php
class UserContact extends ActiveRecord {
    public function getUser(){
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id']);
    }
}
```

**Query**

```php
User::find()->joinWith('userContacts', false)
    ->where(['userContact.email' => $email])
    ->one();
```

I follow the instruction given [here.](http://www.yiiframew...in-yii-2-0/#hh4)

Is there a way to have the alias in the query?

Comment: That link is _really_ broken. Could you please paste the full URL of what you were looking at in a comment or edit it into the question?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34468405/yii2-filter-on-related-model-where-relation-name-is-lower-camelcase/34468772#34468772

Comment: Hi, I follow the instruction here: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/780/drills-search-by-a-has_many-relation-in-yii-2-0/#hh7

Comment: Thank for for your answer arogachev. I am using the solution give in your link at this moment. And what if i have two relations to the same table? I guess i need a table alias to do that. Is it possible in Yii2.0? I can do that in Yii1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Use method "alias('string')".

```
User::find()->alias('u')->joinWith(['userContacts' => function($query) use ($email){
  $query->alias('uc')->where(['uc.email' => $email])
 }])
->one();
```

[Look this API doc](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#alias()-detail)

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, your user table is called `tbl_user_contact`. However, you are referring to it as `userContact`, which results in the error.

When adding conditions, you should refer to fields using the actual table name. Here's the proper code:

```
User::find()->joinWith('userContacts', false)
    ->where([UserContact::tableName().'.email' => $email])
    ->one();
```

You could just replace `UserContact::tableName().'.email'` with `tbl_user_contact.email`, but using `tableName()` is better practice.

Comment: Thank for your answer. This is the current solution i am using. And what if i have two relations to the same table? I guess i need a table alias to do that. Is it possible in Yii2.0? I can do that in Yii1.1.

Comment: I think you're out of luck (at least for many-to-many relations). Here's the [relevant issue](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/2377). There is a workaround for one-to-many, though.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveQuery extends of Query, you can use methods of query in ActiveQuery:

```
    $query = \app\models\db\AnuncioConsulta::find();
    $query->from(\app\models\db\AnuncioConsulta::tableName() . ' as ac' );

    $query->join = [
       ['INNER JOIN', 'anuncio as a'  , ' a.id = ac.anuncio_id AND a.status = 1 '],
       ['INNER JOIN', 'autor as au'   , ' au.id = a.autor_id AND au.agente_inmobiliario = 0 '],
       ['INNER JOIN', 'usuario as u'  , ' u.id = au.object_id '],
    ];

    $query->andWhere('ac.news      =:status' , [':status' =>  1 ]);
    $query->andWhere('ac.delete    =:status' , [':status' =>  0 ]);
    $query->andWhere('u.id         =:userId' , [':userId' => Yii::$app->user->id ]);

    return new \yii\data\ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
```