# Yii2 filter on related model where relation name is lower camelCase

Tags: php, yii2

I've successfully been working through implementing http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/653/displaying-sorting-and-filtering-model-relations-on-a-gridview/. Which has been working fine where my relation name is just a single word. But where my relation name is something like `subSector` I'm getting: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subSector.sub_sector' in 'where clause'`.

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = Product::find();
    // add in relation to be able to search with
    $query->joinWith(['sector', 'subSector'];
...
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['sub_sector_search'] = [
    // The tables are the ones our relation are configured to
    'asc' => ['subSector.sub_sector' => SORT_ASC],
    'desc' => ['subSector.sub_sector' => SORT_DESC],
    ];
...
$query->andFilterWhere([
'product_id' => $this->product_id,
...
])
->andFilterWhere(['like', 'subSector.sub_sector', $this->sub_sector_search])
```

I've also added the parameter below the class initialization and added the safe term in the rules.

So far all 3 single word relations work for filtering and both model relations that are camelCase return `unknown column`.

Comment: what is your `subSector` relation TableName

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
->andFilterWhere(['like', Subsector::tableName() . '.sub_sector', $this->sub_sector_search])
```

and so on.

This will resolve duplicate columns problem and if the table name will change in the future, you just only need to change `tableName()` method in your model without replacing it in all filters, etc.

Framework interprets this: `'subSector.sub_sector'` as just column name prefixed with table name, so if your table named differently than `subSector`, for example `subsectors`, it won't work.